# Remark 3.1.3 of Lectures on the Ricci flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow

About Theorem 3.1.1, Remark 3.1.3 state that the strong maximum principle means a better results. I find the strong maximum principle from Evans' book which is in 3th picture below. The operator $L$ is
$$
Lu = -a^{ij}u_{ij} +b^i u_i +cu
$$
where $u_i =\partial_i u$. But seemly, the term $F(u,t)$ can't be deal by $cu$. Therefore, I want to know which strong maximum principle I should use ?

PS: I find a new strong maximum principle in The Ricci flow Techniques and Applications Part II: Analytic Aspects,  which is contained in 4th 5th pictures below. But seemly, it also can't deal the $F(u,t)$. In fact, after finding book, I feel the Remark 3.1.3 maybe wrong. But I am not sure.

---

> > > [image]

> > > [image]

---

> > > [image]

---

> > > [image]

> > > [image]

Comment: I don't know why you are switching in various books, but a simple and intuitive explanation of S-Max-P can be found in [Terry Tao Webpage](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/285g-lecture-3-the-maximum-principle-and-the-pinching-phenomenon/)

Comment: @C.F.G  Thanks your help. I just want to find a suitable S-Max-P. Therefore, various books I switch.  In fact, I think I should to prove a suitable S-Max-P, But I am too lazy and timid to try.